# Regular expression for Landline Number

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

My scenario:

i want to expect regular expression for following number

```
     +(91)-(44)-96217000
     +(91)-44-96217000
```

i try this expression is not working

```
    static bool IsPhone(string s)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\(?\d{2}\)?[\s\-]?\d{3}\-?\d{10}");
    }
```

Comment: And in case somebody disagrees with my duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+phone

Comment: The site http://regexlib.com/ has very very very many regular expressions precooked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing you're asking for a cluster of 3 digits when you expect 2 and a cluster of 10 when you expect 8 - I don't know what valid phone numbers are wherever you are but your examples won't match that.

I can also see a problem with your attempt to match the parens - with what you have both `(91-44...` and `91)-44...` would be accepted. Regex OR `|` is your friend here I think.

Can't help you much more without knowing your locale, and if I were you and knew that I'd google for an appropriate phone regex - these things are non-trivial.

Comment: 91 is the country code of India.

Comment: @"\\(?\d{2}\\)?[\s\-]?\d{2}\-?\d{8}|\\(?\d{2}\\)?[\s\-]?\\(?\d{2}\\)-?\d{8}"